# Delete all Cookies in Electron desktop app

Tags: webview, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, electron, desktop-application

I am using oauth (Stack Overflow) in an electron desktop app and there is a webview which loads the oauth url. I have a signout button in my app which will signout the user from Stack Overflow website and also from the app. How can I do this ?

How to remove all session cookies from the webview in electron app ?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove cookies using Electron's `cookies.remove()` function (https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/cookies/#cookiesremoveurl-name-callback)

The trick is to convert `cookie.domain` into `url`.

```
import { session } from 'electron';

export default function deleteAllCookies() {
  session.defaultSession.cookies.get({}, (error, cookies) => {
    cookies.forEach((cookie) => {
      let url = '';
      // get prefix, like https://www.
      url += cookie.secure ? 'https://' : 'http://';
      url += cookie.domain.charAt(0) === '.' ? 'www' : '';
      // append domain and path
      url += cookie.domain;
      url += cookie.path;

      session.defaultSession.cookies.remove(url, cookie.name, (error) => {
        if (error) console.log(`error removing cookie ${cookie.name}`, error);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all cookies cleared, this would be the most straightforward way.

```js
const { session } = require('electron');

session.defaultSession.clearStorageData({storages: ['cookies']})
        .then(() => {
            console.log('All cookies cleared');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Failed to clear cookies: ', error);
        });
```

It supports more complex requests. You can check the documentation [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/session#sesclearstoragedataoptions).